# Error with clerk auth() outside app directory

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js13, clerk

Here's my code:

```
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import { $notes } from "@/lib/db/schema";
import { generateImage, generateImagePrompt } from "@/lib/openai";
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const runtime = "edge";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const { userId } = auth();
  if (!userId) {
    return new NextResponse("unauthorised", { status: 401 });
  }
  const body = await req.json();
  const { name } = body;
  const image_description = await generateImagePrompt(name);
  if (!image_description) {
    return new NextResponse("failed to generate image description", {
      status: 500,
    });
  }
  const image_url = await generateImage(image_description);
  if (!image_url) {
    return new NextResponse("failed to generate image ", {
      status: 500,
    });
  }

  const note_ids = await db
    .insert($notes)
    .values({
      name,
      userId,
      imageUrl: image_url,
    })
    .returning({
      insertedId: $notes.id,
    });

  return NextResponse.json({
    note_id: note_ids[0].insertedId,
  });
}
```

i get this error:

> ⨯ node_modules@clerk\nextjs\dist\esm\app-router\server\utils.js (10:10) @ buildRequestLike
> ⨯ Clerk: auth() and currentUser() are only supported in App Router (/app directory).
> If you're using /pages, try getAuth() instead.
> Original error: Error: Invariant: headers() expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available.
> null

Can anyone help me solve this? I can't understand what am i doing wrong or how to use the auth inside of the app directory if i need it in my api

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Took me time to solve it but the issue is that `auth()` shall not be used in api routes, so you should use instead `const { userId } = getAuth(req);` and import `import { getAuth } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";` in your route.ts, which [clerk mentions here](https://clerk.com/docs/quickstarts/nextjs#api-routes).

Hope it helps!